# Manipulate innerHtml on onMouseOver()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple navigation bar that looks something like this:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

So a very simple navigation. When a user hovers over one of the links I'd like to add squiggly brackets on either side of the link text as in:

> Home {About Us} Prodcuts Contact Us

The way I thought is that I could do this in javascript, adding onClick="navAnimation('TheLinkName')" on each  tag. Then in the JS I just get the innerHTML of the given link tag and add the squigglys on either side of the text.

Is this the best way to do it? It seems like quite alot of work for something so trivial..

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS, using pseudo elements:

```
ul.navigation a:hover:before { content: "{"; }
ul.navigation a:hover:after { content: "}"; }
```

Comment: It may be worthwhile placing them there always, and toggling their `visibility `, so they don't make the other items jump (depending on the OP's layout, of course).

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @elclanrs - I just noticed that it works in webkit browers but not in IE.. Like that's a surprise, a way to make this cross-browser?

Comment: And I'm talking about IE 10 here

Comment: Wow, no idea. Pretty sure this should work on IE9+... Let me test on my VM.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best way would be to handle the "onmouseover" event on the A or the LI element.

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a onmouseover="AddBrackets(this);" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a onmouseover="AddBrackets(this); href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a onmouseover="AddBrackets(this); href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a onmouseover="AddBrackets(this); href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the AddBrackets function would be something like:

```
function AddBrackets(x) {
    x.innerHTML = "{" + x.innerHTML + "}";
}
```

does it sound like what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pseudo` class `after and before`

**CSS**

```
ul li{display:inline; padding:2px 6px; color:green; text-align:center}
ul li a{display:inline; color:green; width:100px; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block}
ul li a:hover:after{ content:"}" }
ul li a:hover:before{ content:"{" }
```

​**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nVkqR/1/)**